# MomentJS not working correctly in meteor

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, meteor, momentjs

I am using copleykj:livestamp and the required momentjs package (also tried the official package).
I have got a date in the future (ISODate) and want to format it in a user readable text like "in x days".

I have got this Helper setup:

```
Template.registerHelper('formatRight', function(date) {
  return moment(date).toNow();
});
```

And this inside the template:

```
<div class="description">{{formatRight reldate}}</div>
```

But apparently I have got this error

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: moment(...).toNow is not a function
```

I tried also other ways like using to variables and then a.to(b); but then I get the error that "to" is not a function.
The weird thing is that ".fromNow" is working without any problems.

I cannot figure out why.

I also tried to remove the livestamp package and the required momentjs package and using the official one but that did not work too.

Comment: [toNow](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/tonow/) apparently requires `v2.10.3`. `copleykj:livestamp` currently uses an older version - `v2.9.0`.

Comment: Is there a meteor package which uses this version?

Comment: I have fixed it and the solution was more than simple :D I have looked into the versions I have installed and noticed that meteor has installed an old version of moment because another package was not up to date. So I simply run a meteor update and everything is working now

Comment: I experienced another problem that at some time meteor did not really update the packages. I had 3 packages left for update but every time I run meteor update it says it has updated it but when I run it once again it told me the same thing. The solution was to add the package by providing the version number manually.

Comment: Not specifying the version number can indeed lead so some [unexpected results](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Packaging-UX-Gravity-Hurts-FoTnLTVUklt).